# serve django staticfiles with nginx

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, nginx-config

i have django back-end and reactjs front-end.
i want to load static files of django back-end with nginx but he can't find anything .
gunicorn can find django pages but can't load staticfiles

so i want nginx to serve django page and staticfiles.

this is my settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static')
```

docker-compose :

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:

  backend:
    build: 
      context: ./backend
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    entrypoint: ./entrypoint.sh
 #   command: gunicorn server.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - static:/static

  nginx:
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./webserver/Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - static:/static
    depends_on:
      - backend

      
volumes:
  static:
```

and this is my default.conf :

```
upstream api {
    server backend:8000;
}


server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  myapp.loc;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }  

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  newapp.loc;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/frontend2;
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /admin/ {
        proxy_pass http://api;
    }  

    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Comment: show `backend` DOCKERFILE

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem occurs in the nginx config file.

```
    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }
```

Just now, it will alias to `FRONTEND_ROOT/static/` (in this case, it is `/usr/share/nginx/html/frontend1/static/`), but what we expected is it should alias to `BACKEND_ROOT/static/`.

So the easiest way to solve this problem is to write absolute path here, to avoid alias to the frontend directory.

Comment: you mean root path?

Comment: @toufik-benkhelifa : I mean in the config file that you gave, you used relative path when you configuring the alias of `static`, and at this case, nginx will find folder `static` in your frontend folder, which is not correct. In my understanding, serving files in `BACKEND_PATH/static` is expected, so you can use absolute path to ensure nginx find files in the correct place.

Comment: so what should i change exactly? i didn't understand you

Comment: @toufik-benkhelifa : old: `alias /static/;` new: `alias /path/to/backend/static/;` and replace `/path/to/backend` to you real backend path, which is same with the value of `BASE_DIR` in your `settings.py`

Answer (score 0):

Create seperate entry in /etc/hosts for `django.loc`

Also make nginx configure for your back which will redirect you, changes in default.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  django.loc;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
    }
    location /static/ {
        alias /path/to/backend/static/;
    } #OR YOU DONT NEED THIS, TELL BACKEND THAT ALLOW ACCESS TO STATIC
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

Either specify complete path in static block, or else remove static path, and mention static directory in your framework.

Try this if not working let me know